# Add array elements one by one in a "for" loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to add the array values one by one to an URL since each one is a different ID for an API call im trying to make.

The code works if I write the ID directly in the URL variable. But I have hundreds of API calls to make.

How can I print/add each array element one by one and the URL? Check the final output code and see how it adds the whole array instead of each element one by one.

```
import requests

ids = ["12ab", "13ab", "14ab"]

for x in ids:
  url = ("https://google.com/{}"+format(ids)+"?extraurlparameters")
  response = requests.request("DELETE", url)
  print(x)
  print(url)

print(response.text)
```

output

```
12ab
1
https://google.com/{}['12ab', '13ab', '14ab']?extraurlparameters
2
13ab
3
https://google.com/{}['12ab', '13ab', '14ab']?extraurlparameters
4
14ab
5
https://google.com/{}['12ab', '13ab', '14ab']?extraurlparameters
6
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I want the code to output: 
https://google.com/12ab?extraurlparameters
https://google.com/13ab?extraurlparameters
https://google.com/14ab?extraurlparameters

instead of  https://google.com/{}['12ab', '13ab', '14ab']?extraurlparameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your version with the following and let me know if it works

```py
ids = ["12ab", "13ab", "14ab"]
for x in ids:
    url = ("https://google.com/{}".format(x)+"?extraurlparameters")
    print(url)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked like magic! 
I'll mark it as the solution in a few minutes once the site allows me to.
One more Q if you can help:

If you notice the " response = requests.request("DELETE", url) " line, it deletes the data in that specific url. It works if I add the url manually, but with the for loop it's not doing anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I simply forgot to add "?" before the parameters. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
ids = ["12ab", "13ab", "14ab"]
for x in ids: 
    url = ("https://google.com/"+format(x)+"?extraurlparameters") 
    response = requests.request("DELETE", url) 
    print(x) 
    print(url)
    print(response.text)
```

change ids to x in line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `format()` is called at the end of the string.

```
url = "https://google.com/{}?extraurlparameters".format(x)
```

In Python 3.6+, you could use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (format string), such as:

```
url = f"https://google.com/{x}?extraurlparameters"
```

### Original code sample

```
import requests

ids = ["12ab", "13ab", "14ab"]

for x in ids:
  url = "https://google.com/{}?extraurlparameters".format(x)
  response = requests.request("DELETE", url)
  print(x)
  print(url)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misuse the format function:

```
import requests

ids = ["12ab", "13ab", "14ab"]

for id in ids:
  url = ("https://google.com/{}?extraurlparameters".format(id))
  response = requests.request("DELETE", url)
  print(id)
  print(url)

print(response.text)
```